# CSS position fixed to the left but not top

Tags: css

I have an events calendar. Dates are displayed on the left of the screen.
Current display has the full year view so it has 365 rows of days. 
I want to keep the dates are visible even if the user scrolls to the right.
But also when the user scrolls to the bottom dates have to scroll too.
All I want to do is use the css position:fixed but only left:0 but top will not be 0.

here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Calendar</title>
<style>
html{color:#000;background:#FFF;}body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,fieldset,legend,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{margin:0;padding:0;}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}fieldset,img{border:0;}address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;}li{list-style:none;}caption,th{text-align:left;}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:normal;}q:before,q:after{content:'';}abbr,acronym{border:0;font-variant:normal;}sup{vertical-align:text-top;}sub{vertical-align:text-bottom;}input,textarea,select{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit;}input,textarea,select{*font-size:100%;}legend{color:#000;}

body{
    background: #fff;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Arial,Sans;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 19px;
    padding: 0 0 0 70px;
    text-align: left;
    width:5000px;
}
.cal{
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 5000px;
}
.dayrow{    border-bottom: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
    height: 19px;
    }
.dayrow:hover{background:#000;opacity:0.2;}
.header{font-weight:bold;}

.date{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EFEFEF;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 5px 0 0;
    text-align: right;
    width: 90px;
}
.columnOK{height:19px;width: 149px; border-right: 1px solid #bbb;float:left;}   
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="cal">

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">11 October</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">12 October</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>


    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">13 October</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">14 October</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">15 October</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">16 October</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">17 October</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">18 October</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>


    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">19 October</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">20 October</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">21 October</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">22 October</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">23 October</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">24 October</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>


    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">25 October</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">26 October</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">27 October</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">28 October</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">29 October</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">30 October</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>


    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">31 October</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;"> 1 November</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;"> 2 November</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;"> 3 November</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;"> 4 November</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>


    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;"> 5 November</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;"> 6 November</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;"> 7 November</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;"> 8 November</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;"> 9 November</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>


    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">10 November</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">11 November</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">12 November</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">13 November</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">14 November</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">15 November</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>


    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">16 November</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">17 November</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">18 November</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">19 November</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">20 November</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">21 November</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>


    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">22 November</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">23 November</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">24 November</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">25 November</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">26 November</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">27 November</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>


    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">28 November</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">29 November</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">30 November</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;"> 1 December</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;"> 2 December</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>


    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;"> 3 December</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;"> 4 December</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;"> 5 December</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;"> 6 December</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;"> 7 December</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>


    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;"> 8 December</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;"> 9 December</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">10 December</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">11 December</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">12 December</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>


    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">13 December</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">14 December</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">15 December</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">16 December</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">17 December</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>

    <div class="dayrow"><div class="date" style="float:left;">18 December</div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div><div class="columnOK"></div></div>


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Showing your code would be helpful.

Comment: Code is very big to post for now but maybe you can get an idea from the image http://imgur.com/BdNQ7

Comment: This may not be possible with pure CSS. `position: fixed` means fixed in both directions. You may have to resort to JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of a crude solution but a solution..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onscroll = function (){
left =  window.pageXOffset ? window.pageXOffset : document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft;
    var cal = document.getElementById("cal");
    for(i = 0 ;i<cal.childNodes.length ; i++)
    if(cal.childNodes[i].className == "dayrow")cal.childNodes[i].firstChild.style.left = left + "px";
    }
</script>
```

Change this in your html --

```
<div id="cal"  class="cal">
```

Its a quick fix.. but since your displaying all the dates i wouldnt recommend resorting to this.. if your willing to change the layout,i could give u a better solution..

the rendering is a bit bad as the JS is quite extensive -- I'm not saying its the best,but a solution that does work..

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pjfJd)

Comment: your script did not work for me. What would you recommend for the layout change.

Comment: I've tested it, and it works.. how can it not work!!.. check the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/pjfJd/ .. and the layout change - make the date part in one single element -- withing which all the dates are there , hence u need to change the style of only 1 element ergo less load on the JS ( browser )..

Comment: I didn't get the layout change though.(- make the date part in one single element -- withing which all the dates are there)

Comment: I was looking for a solution for hours! This is amazing thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here is a tutorial on how to have an element fixed horizontally but floating vertically when the browser scrolls.   start from this and play with the vertical positioning until you get what you want.

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/

or alternately you could show us your css and html so we better understand what you have tried